# While using REST API to get a list by title, there is a problem getting a list whose name contains the '&' character

Tags: rest, encoding

I have already tried encoding the '&' as %26 in the request URL.
It didn't work.
Please suggest something else.

Comment: Can you show your REST call?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the '&' character and try i.e. for list named AT&T, try ATT.